# css only flexible layout of resizing images on change of screen size

Tags: css, image, resize

After much research and trial and error, I humbly ask you CSS gurus out there for some help. This is what I need:

I have two images: titlelogo and newlogo.

In full screen, newlogo needs to be on the left and titlelogo on the right (this can be either flush with the full width of the screen or "centered" with space in between - as long as it "looks nice" which is the standard company line).

When resizing the screen/for mobile, titlelogo needs to be on top and newlogo needs to be beneath it. Both images now need to be centered.

(Please don't criticize the inline css - there's no way around using it based on other factors that don't apply to this scenario.)

Here's what I have, which is nice for full screen, but fails to center when the screen is a different size:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="https://secure.etransfer.com/images/titlelogo.png" style="float:right;height:auto;width: auto\9;overflow-y:visible;" />
<img src="https://secure.etransfer.com/images/newlogo.jpg" style="float:left;height:auto;width: auto\9;" />
</div>
```

Comment: you'll need to add some media queries to the CSS. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Take a look at this for media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: If you cant change that inline css you can use `!important` like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/265/

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: Not in this universe. It's unfortunate since I know the media queries are probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: @MCB but you can add inline styles?

Comment: inline styles is a-okay

Comment: why not add the media queries just below the images between `<style> @media(){} </style>` tags?

Comment: Aaron, I liked your idea, but there is an issue with our system and the {}...it chokes on them in this scenario. I can't even "trick" it by using &#123; and &#124;   Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of flex layout.

> In full screen, newlogo needs to be on the left and titlelogo on the
>   right (this can be either flush with the full width of the screen or
>   "centered" with space in between

This can be done by styling the container `div`, like this:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
```

`justify-content` property defines how the flexed items will be justified within the available width of the flex container. The property value of `space-between` will justify the items by distributing the remaining width *between* the items.

This will align your images to left and right respectively.

> When resizing the screen/for mobile, titlelogo needs to be on top and
>   newlogo needs to be beneath it. Both images now need to be centered.

To do this without media queries, you will need to add `auto` for left and right `margin`s on your images. Like this:

```
<img src="..." style="margin: 0 auto;" />
```

This will center the images within the available width. Thus when the screen width is too small (like on mobile), the images will wrap because of the `flex-wrap: wrap` property on the container `div` and will be centered because of the `margin: 0 auto`.

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lv4omou7/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <img src="//placehold.it/128x64/33e" style="margin: 0 auto;" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/128x64/e3e" style="margin: 0 auto;" />
</div>
```

***Note 1***: This will have the side-effect of images not flushing to the extreme left and right when in full-screen or larger widths. But, this is what you are okay with as per your question.

***Note 2***: Inline CSS is not a good practice. Try to stay away from that as far as possible.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't meet the requirement of the full screen having newlogo needs to be on the left and titlelogo on the right versus the mobile screen having titlelogo on the top and newlogo on the bottom.  I know inline is "bad" but the way it is, is the way it is in this particular case.

Comment: @MCB: This meets the requirement that you yourself stated in the question -- *"this can be either flush with the full width of the screen or "centered" with space in between.."*. This solution gives you the images centered with space between. Maybe am not being able to understand something?

Comment: There are 2 images. Full screen - newlogo on left; titlelogo on right. Mobile screen: titlelogo on top, newlogo on bottom.

Comment: @mcb: Open the fiddle I linked to. Try reducing the width of the results pane, to simulate a mobile screen. When the width is small the images get on top of each other centered.

Comment: Your full screen version is good, but in mobile, the pink one needs to be on top of the blue one.

Comment: changing `flex:wrap` to `flex:wrap-reverse` did the trick. Thanks to @Abhitalks for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

changing flex:wrap to flex:wrap-reverse did part of the trick. Since the images were different heights, I had to make some other adjustments too. In case anyone finds themselves in this situation in the future, I am putting my final version here. (Thanks to @Abhitalks for putting me on the right track!)

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;">
  <img src="newlogo.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto;" />
  <img src="titlelogo.png" style="margin: 0 auto;width:auto;height:1%;align-self:center;" />
</div>
```